# PHP failed to open stream: Is a directory

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, file-permissions, expressionengine

Very simple PHP script I'm running within an EE template on an Ubuntu Webserver I set up personally.

I know it has something to do with permissions, and I've already changed the owner of the directory I'm trying to write as being the Apache user.

```
<?php 

$dir = 'export';

$drop =' {exp:ajw_export 
    sql="SELECT member_id, screen_name, email FROM exp_members" 
    format="xml" 
} ';

echo $dir;

file_put_contents($dir, $drop);

?>
```

Error I get is:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: file_put_contents(export): failed to open stream: Is a
>   directory
>
> Filename: libraries/Functions.php(689) : eval()'d code
>
> Line Number: 16

Comment: You will need to define the path and the file name in `file_put_contents`, not just the directory name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that you're not defining the actual file, only a directory.

```
$file = $dir . '/export.txt';
file_put_contents($file, $drop);
```

Otherwise, how will PHP know where to place the content?